# How Do I Whitelist Email Domains In Signup With Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using simple email signup for Azure B2C and not SSO and my user flow is the basic one from this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows

At the moment I am using temporary email addresses for my testing, however, when I go live I want to whitelist the domains that people can sign up with.

How do I do this whitelisting?

Comment: Are you looking to restrict the users from Signup when they are not from whitelisted domain.?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Using Azure AD B2C Userflows we can't Whitelist the users while signup based on the email domain. We Need to handle it using Custom policies by calling the Rest API and need to validate the email address.

Please go through the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro) and [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/rest-api) on using Custom policies with Rest API.

A Restful technical profile provides support for interfacing with your own RESTful service. Azure AD B2C sends data to the RESTful service in an `InputClaims` collection and receives data back in an `OutputClaims` collection. Find the ClaimsProviders element in your

Configure the REST API technical profile

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetProfile">
      <DisplayName>Get user extended profile Azure Function web hook</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://your-account.azurewebsites.net/api/GetProfile?code=your-code</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userLanguage" PartnerClaimType="lang" DefaultValue="{Culture:LCID}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Claims parsed from your REST API -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="balance" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

You need to handle the Email validation logic in your REST API. The above Provideed document links helps you in building the custom policy.

This limitation is already raised in the Azure Feedback uservoice and to consider this feature request for the future, please upvote on the [existing UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/9065a5fc-b025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789).
That way the product group can prioritize this accordingly.

Comment: Can you add some code here on custom policies. Link only answers are not encouraged https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Comment: I don’t think you need REST API here. Use a claims transform to parse the domain, then do the lookup claims transform to return a Boolean on whether the domain is known. Then use an assert Boolean claims transform to throw an error if known domain came back as false.

Comment: UserVoice link is dead

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this policy here https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-up-domain-allowlist regex to allowlist

```
 <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~\-]+@(outlook[.]com|live[.]com|gmail[.]com)" HelpText="Please enter a email address from one of the following domains: outlook.com, live.com." />
```